# localStorage.length not updating after removing item (javascript)

Tags: javascript

I have this:

```
var delItem = localStorage.length;

window.alert("this should be localStorage.length: " + delItem);

localStorage.removeItem(delItem); //removing the last item on storage

window.alert("length after removing item: " + localStorage.length);
```

Can somebody tell me why I am getting the same length before and after I removed an item?

A detail that I ignore if it is of any importance: the key/value pairs I stored are of the form 'number'/'string' ,example: '1'/ '5*3456=17280'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example it seems that you may be using a 0 based index for your key/values but you are not taking that into account when you get the length and then try to remove that item from `localStorage`.

Try the following edit to see if it works.

```
localStorage.removeItem(delItem-1); //removing the last item on storage
```

Answer (score 2):

`localStorage.removeItem` takes the key of item with which you used to store a value previously, if the passed key does not resolve to a known stored key/value pair, nothing is deleted. `delItem` is the number of key/value pairs currently in `localStorage`, after you call `removeItem`, you are still getting the same value for `localStorage.length` it means the key you are passing to `removeItem`, which is `delItem`, does not correspond to a value that was previously stored, in another word, that key does not exist

Comment: Thanks to you too for answering, both answers helped, I voted his because I had to choose one and his might be better for people with this problem.